# Using scanf and then checking if it was filled

Tags: c, char

I am learning C and I have a program that gets the user input using scanf (insecure I know but it is for my learning only). The issue I am having is that in one part of the code I check if `input[0] == 'n'`, then I do one thing and I have another command check further down that checks if my input is equal to 'n', 'o'.

**My issue** is that if I send in 'no' then the first check gets met. I solved this by doing `input[0] == 'n' && input[1] == NULL` but now I get the following error: `warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('char' and 'void *')`

How do I check if there was only one character met or how do I, not by using compiler flags, solve this error. I want more clean code. I do not have a "minimally reproducible example" because this code is (1) simple enough and (2) my code is messy and there is no benefit to copy pasting and trying for 15 minutes because... well... reason 1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `input[0] == 'n' && input[1] == '\0'`, NULL is s pointer type, or you could just use `strlen(input) == 1`.

Comment: I don't seen any `scanf` code

Comment: "there is no benefit to copy pasting and trying for 15 minutes " --> The benefit is for others to help make a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I check if there was only one character met

Test if the 2nd character in the array is a *null character*.

```
// if (input[0] == 'n' && input[1] == NULL)
if (input[0] == 'n' && input[1] == '\0')
```

`NULL` is best used for testing if a pointer equates to a *null pointer*.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Another solution was to check the length using string.h's strlen. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking, if it's not feel free to let me know. I think you want to check 3 cases: your input is `no`(first check and second check ok), your input is not `no` (first check and second check failed) and your input is `n + something!='o'` (first check ok, second check failed).
If that's what you need I would do it like that:

```
char input[2];

printf("Insert input: ");
scanf(" %s", input);


// first check
if (input[0]=='n') {
    printf("first check ok\n");
    /* do stuff */
    if (input[1]=='o') {
        printf("second check ok\n");
        /* do stuff */
    }
}
else {
    printf("first check failed\n");
}
```

Comment: `input[2];` is only big enough to hold up to a string of length 1.  `scanf(" %s", input);`, lacking a width limit, can readily overflow.  Recommend to use a larger buffer, add a width limit, drop unneeded leading space in format and check `scanf()` result.

Comment: For the buffer size I just assumed he expects only inputs of max length 2. For sure using a larger buffer is better in general. Check scanf result is for sure needed, agree.

Comment: "I just assumed he expects only inputs of max length 2." --> then `char input[2];` should have been `char input[3];` to accommodate data like `'n'`, `'o'`, `'\0'` and `if (scanf("%2s", input) == 1) Success_do_rest_of_code();`